# Kubernetes node without master

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

Cluster consists of one master and one worker node. If the master is down and worker is restarted no workloads (deployments) are started on boot. How and if it is possible to make worker resume last state without master?

Kubernetes 1.18.3

On worker node are installed: kubelet, kubectl, kubeadm

Comment: when you say workload what you mean? Master nodes typically don't run workload. Also does the master node has etcd as well? Did you lose the data in etcd?

Comment: I have added missing info to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have more than one(typically a odd number like 3 or 5) node serving as master and accessible from worker nodes via a LoadBalancer.

The state is stored in ETCD which is accessed by worker nodes via the API Server. So without master nodes running there is no way for workers to know the desired state.

Although it's not recommended you but can use [static pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/) as potential solution here.Static Pods are managed directly by the kubelet daemon on a specific node, without the API server observing them.Unlike Pods that are managed by the control plane (for example, a Deployment ), instead the kubelet watches each static Pod (and restarts it if it crashes).

The caveat of using static pod is since those pods are not dependent on API Server Hence static Pods cannot be managed with kubectl or other Kubernetes API clients.